# Using 'sed' to replace a string

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a file that contains a URL and I wish to replace this URL with a new one.
This URL can be different each time so I do not wish to replace XXX with YYY but to change the value of a variable which contains the URL.

File looks like this:

```
APP_URL=https://test.hello.co/
```

I wish to change the value of APP_URL to a different URL but without success.
I am using a bash script in order to make this work.

tried using this inside my script and it didn't work.

```
oldline='APP_URL=https://test.hello.co'
newline='APP_URL=https://${variable}'
sudo sed -i 's/${oldline}/${newline}/g' .env
```

I would love to get help here!

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the `'` in sed and escape all `/` so that it doesn't think you are ending the part of `s` (or use other sign)
Both these work (my filename is `.test`):

```
variable=aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa

oldline='APP_URL=\S+'
newline='APP_URL=https:\/\/'$variable
sed -r s/${oldline}/${newline}/g .test

oldline='APP_URL=\S+'
newline='APP_URL=https://'$variable
sed -r s-${oldline}-${newline}-g .test
```

Comment: That's going to read `${variable}` as a literal...

Comment: That's not reading my ${variable} but instead placing it inside the string.
Can I make this work if lets say I don't know what is the value of 'APP_URL='?
I want the sed to replace any URL that comes after to my ''APP_URL=https://${variable}'' and of course it should read my variable from the script.

Thank you!!

Comment: Edited the answer to match `APP_URL=<a string of things that are not whitespaces>` and not use `variable` as literal

Answer (score 0):

Single quotes prevent variable interpolation.

You can usually use double quotes instead.

```
$: cat tst
oldurl=test.hello.co
newurl=foo.bar.com
sed "s,APP_URL=https://${oldurl}/,APP_URL=https://${newurl}/,g" file

$: cat file
APP_URL=https://test.hello.co/

$: ./tst
APP_URL=https://foo.bar.com/
```

## edit

Yes, this can be simplified a lot, such as by passing in the new url.

```
$: grep . tst file
tst:sed -E "s,APP_URL=https://[^/]+/,APP_URL=https://$1/,g" file
file:APP_URL=https://test.hello.co/

$: ./tst a.b.c
APP_URL=https://a.b.c/
```

Comment: Useful, thanks.
Can I make this work if lets say I don't know what is the value of 'APP_URL='? 
I want the sed to replace any URL that comes after to my ''APP_URL=https://${variable}'' and of course it should read my variable from my script. Thank you!! –